# Combine vue props with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Here's sample of my child component
HTML:

```
<div v-for="(input, index) in form.inputs" :key="index">
  <div>
    <input :name"input.name" :type="input.type" />
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript (Vue):

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "child",
    props: ['parentForm'],
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          inputs: [
            {
              name: 'name',
              type: 'text'
          ],
          [...]
        }
      }
    }
```

And sample of root component
HTML:

```
<child :parentsForm="form"></child>
```

JavaScript (Vue):

```
<script>
  import child from "./child";

  export default {
    name: "root",
    components: { child },
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          data: {
            name: null,
            email: null,
            ...
          }
      }
    }
```

The question is, how do I achieve combining root + v-for?

Example I want to using child component this way

```
<input :name"input.name" :type="input.type" v-model="parentForm.data . input.name" />
```

Since parentForm.data will bind form:data:{ and this will be the variable get from input.name }

Output in v-model should be bind `form.data.name` or `form.data.email` on root component

Thank you

Comment: You have a typo in the props or bindings. You call it `parentsForm` and `parentForm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it as per follow,

```html
<input :name="input.name" :type="input.type" v-model="parentForm.data[input.name]" />
```

This will bind `parentForm.data.name` for `input.name = 'name'` to `v-model`.

Comment: This actually work.. but I don't get the fundamental, isn't `parentForm.data[input.name]` refer to array not an object?

Comment: Actually if you see fundamentals, even array is a type of object, so, when you use associative array, it is nothing but an object in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to update parent data from your child component. If yes then you have two options.

1. In you child component use `$parent.form.data` to bind.
2. Or you can pass it down as `prop` assign it to a `data` property in child. Bind this new data property in your child and `emit` it whenever any changes are made. Receive this `emit` in your parent and update the parent property respectively (Recommended)